# Apache RewriteCond - Works local, not on Host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess rewrite condition / rule, which works fine on my local, which is OSX mavericks, running apache Apache/2.2.26, but when I deploy to my production server it no longer works, running Apache/2.2.22 (Debian).

this is the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([a-z]{2})/sitemap.xml$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/sitemap.xml /sitemaps/$1_sitemap.xml [NC,L]
```

As you can see, I have a directory for sitemaps in the base directory, and this being a multi-lingual site, I have a sitemap for each language. However I cannot simply create a directory like `/en/sitemap.xml` for each one, as this effects how the framework deals with the request, as apache trys to serve the directory, rather than passing it to the index file to be handled.

So i create this rewrite condition, which should rewrite the request `/en/sitemap.xml` to `/sitemaps/en_sitemap.xml` and as stated, this works great locally, but not on my Debian server, it never matches that regex from the request, it just moves onto the next one and passes the request to the index.php file.. which is wrong!

Any advice / help would be great, I cannot find anything in apache docs referring to mod_rewrite under these 2 versions that may be different.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `%{REQUEST_URI}` value always begins with a leading slash.
Also, your condition is useless since your `RewriteRule` does the same.

This code should work as expected on both sides

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/$1_sitemap.xml [L]
```

Comment: yeah, i did add leading slashes to them, with no joy. also like i say it works locally!! i'll try this out and see what happens thanks.

Comment: I guess locally (OSX) problem comes from `\.` (escaped dot). Maybe there's no solution to make it work on both sides but the syntax i gave you is the right one

Comment: yeah, all that matters is it works on the server :), this is why I hate macs, always seems to be some inconsistency with them! forced by work to use it though! haha, thanks for your help.